# openCv, create a Mat from a vector of BGR data?

Tags: opencv

I have an array of pixel data that makes up an image. The data is in the format:

`vector<FColor> ColorBuffer;`

where FColor is a struct like this:

```
struct FColor
    {
        uint8 B;
        uint8 G;
        uint8 R;
        uint8 A;
    };
```

I have the image size (Width, Height).

What i need to do is convert this data to a cv::Mat.

I am trying:

```
cv::Mat tester = cv::Mat(Width, Height, CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
        {
            cv::Vec3d px(ColorBuffer[i + j].B, ColorBuffer[i + j].G, ColorBuffer[i + j].R);

            tester.at<cv::Vec3d>(j, i) = px;

        }
    }
```

But this gives me a scrambled image.  Where am I going wrong here? Should i be using something else in place of `cv::Vec3d`? Or do i have the logic wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index for a point inside `ColorBuffer` seems to be incorrect, instead of

```
ColorBuffer[i + j]
```

you should use something like

```
ColorBuffer[i + j*Width]
```

Comment: Thank you! this, in combination with using cv::Vec3b instead of Vec3d, has solved it. Much appreciated.